# Is there any "terraform way" to shutdown a domain?

Tags: terraform, qemu, libvirt, terraform0.12+, virsh

Instead of doing a "virsh undefine " on the host to power-off a VM, is there a way I can do it using terraform?

I tried editing the terraform.tfstate file and trying to do a "terraform plan/apply -replace", but I am hitting some issues, realized that editing tfstate files will not work (and it's not advised to manually edit them)

And trying to modify the  workspace tfvars variable and running apply doesn't "overwrite" it, it throws an error saying domain already exists.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: try to set false in the "running" variable on your libvirt_domain resource. See the doc for reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/dmacvicar/libvirt/latest/docs/resources/domain#running

Comment: @FelipeBonfante manually editing the tfstate file is not recommended is what I saw. But anyways, I set it to false, and tried to do a apply -replace and refresh, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I use terraform-libvirt for my homelab so i searched same answer.
My solution:

first of all i decided to add "running" variable and change in to true o false as i need, but it didn't work.
Then i added null-resource with if-else condition and it worked:

1. add variable

```
variable "vm_condition_poweron" {
  default = true
}
```

2. Put it in `resource "libvirt_domain" "domain-name"` block:

```
resource "libvirt_domain" "domain-ubuntu" {
  running = var.vm_condition_poweron
  count = length(local.vm_common_list_count)
  name = "${local.vm_common_list_count[count.index]}"
```

3. Create null-resource

```
resource "null_resource" "shutdowner" {
  # iterate with for_each over Vms list ( my *.tf file creates VMs from list)
  for_each = toset(local.vm_common_list_count)
  triggers = {
    trigger = var.vm_condition_poweron
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = var.vm_condition_poweron?"echo 'do nothing'":"virsh -c qemu:///system shutdown ${each.value}"
  }
}
```

- or you can create simpler nul_resource ( if you do not use lists for example), but it will shutdown all VMs on your host, not only created by this terraform

```
resource "null_resource" "shutdowner" {
  triggers = {
    trigger = var.vm_condition_poweron
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = var.vm_condition_poweron?"echo 'do nothing'":"for i in $(virsh -c qemu:///system list --all|tail -n+3|awk '{print $2}'); do virsh -c qemu:///system shutdown $i; done"

  }
}
```

4. Execute command

```
terraform apply -auto-approve -var 'vm_condition_poweron=false'
```

- null_resource will be executed every time, but according to if-else statement in command, if you do not need to shutdown vms(vm_condition_poweron=true, by default)- it just echo `do nothing`